# Проводник - как сформировать

Tags: java, swing

Доброго времни суток! п учебе надо сделать "проводник" файлов - чтобы можно было выбрать в выпадающем списке диск и ниже отобразились все файлы на нем. Проблема вот в чем - если рекурсивно формировать дерево из всех файлов, то программа запускается очень долго. Как формировать дерево динамически - то-есть сначала первый уровень папок, при открытии папки динамически добавить её содержимое?

Answer (score 1):

Заведите переменную текущий каталог типа `String currentPath` (или как вариант `File currentDir`), затем:

```
File curDir=new File(currentPath);
String[] fileNames=curDir.list();
// или
File[] files=curDir.listFiles();
```

Далее "проваливание" в каталог разрешено если `File.isDirectory()==true`, в подкаталоге имеем некий объект типа `File`, который становится `currentDir` далее опять вызываем `list()/listFiles()`

Как то так...

Comment: проблема вот в чем - у JTree есть событие раскрытия узла, но я не знаю, как получить доступ к узлу, который был раскрыт, чтобы добавить ему потомков